# Supplements from Europe to Canada

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada

I will be travelling to Canada from Europe and want to pack my fitness supplements with me, these include - small plastic bottle of BCAA pills, pack of creatine and container of protein powder. All of them are in their original packing. Am I better to leave some of these at home to prevent problems or is it fine to take them with me?

Comment: I would have guessed that they were easy to get there.  They might even be cheaper.  A little web surfing might confirm this.  If so then you have removed any danger of trouble and reduced your baggage.  Even if the substances are fine, there is a small danger that they might regard them as disguised drugs.

Comment: I usually take iron, zinc, biotin, and a multi supplement with me for long trips, usually a full 100 pill bottle of each but sometimes I just throw the amount I need into one, or even a plastic food bag. I've never been asked about it throughout Europe, US, and Canada. Not sure about the specific ones you are taking but even if it flags up on scanners, they would just test it for illegal drugs and return them to you when the test is negative